# I want to read a file line by line and split the strings to be used as attributes for a new object

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I'm trying to read from a txt file that has the following format:

```
Matthew:1000
Mark:100
Luke:10
John:0
```

I have a Score object that stores the player's name and score (int). This is the
class for Score:

```
public class Score {

String playerName;
int playerScore;

public String toString(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(playerName + ":" + playerScore);
    return builder.toString();
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.playerName = name;
}

public void setScore(int score){
    this.playerScore = score;
}

  }
```

I would like to read from the file in such a way that I could get the player's
name (Matthew) and their score (1000, stored as an integer), and make a new Score
object. This is the code I've tried so far:

```
    public ArrayList getLoadFile(String filename) {
      ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try{
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String fileLine;

        while((fileLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            Score newScore = new Score();
            newScore.playerName = fileLine.split(":", 0)[0];
            newScore.playerScore = Integer.parseInt(fileLine.split(":", 0)[1]);
            scores.add(newScore);

          }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {             
    } catch (IOException e) {               
    }

    return scores;
}
```

This function is supposed to load string representations of saved scores and
make an ArrayList of scores, then return them to a test function. When I run it, it returns: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to echo e.message() , and show us what's error you get

Comment: I run your code without, there must be something wrong with the incoming text.  Try using `System.out.println(fileLine);` before you try parsing it.  Also, don't throw away your exceptions, at least log them.  And if you open a resources, you should close it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
while((fileLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    String[] splitResults = fileLine.split(":");
    if (splitResults.length > 1) {
        Score newScore = new Score();
        newScore.playerName = splitResults[0];
        newScore.playerScore = Integer.parseInt(splitResults[1]);
        scores.add(newScore);
    }
}
```

This will guarantee that only if `Split` returned at least 2 `Strings` the insert will
be made.

<sup>**Note:** also `Integer.parseInt(String string)` could throw `NumberFormatException`</sup>